# Applying style using javascript doesn't work always

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am applying style to div using JavaScript it appears well at the first time but when I click an image to open a virtual window the applied CSS goes away.

How can I apply style using script that stays forever.

**There is no way left for me to apply any style at design time because I am using ready made user control and I get ID for the DIV only at run time.

Any Idea??

Here is the script I am using...

```
window.onload = changeDivOverflow;
function  changeDivOverflow()
{
   var treeDiv = document.getElementById('T_ctl00contentMainctl04tvw');
   treeDiv.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Comment: Code, examples, and screenshots would help ...

Comment: It's hard to see what your problem is still.  What sort of "virtual window" are you talking about?  Again any more detail that you can add will be of help.  We need more specifics about when the style works, and what is happening to make it stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All styles you apply using javascript and DOM calls, apply only to element you are applying it. In your example it will be only element with ID = 'T_ctl00contentMainctl04tvw'

If you want to reuse that style for more than one element, you should create a CSS class and store that style there. Then apply that class for every element you want. If you want to do it with script, then you should:

```
var treeDiv = document.getElementById('T_ctl00contentMainctl04tvw');
treeDiv.className = "your-class";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ASP.NET, but I cannot see all your full code, I can only assume that your DIV has a `runat="server"` tag and that's why you cannot get the ID on the client side.

If this is the case, you may consider the following change to get the treeDiv:

```
var treeDiv = document.getElementById("<%= tvw.ClientID %>");
```